# Child to Child Form Display month using MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I want to display a selected month in words and not in numbers. Both Form1 and Form2 are child forms of parent MasterForm. Form1 has a MonthCalendar and a button called btnCreate. User will select a month and click the button. After that, Form2 will appear and display the selected month on the Form title.

The code below displays a selected month, in numbers

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "Selected Month: " + e.Start.Month;
}
```

That will display a selected month in Form1 but I want to make it display in Form2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.Start` is a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) object so you can format its string override and, optionally, pass in a particular culture.

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "Selected Month: " + e.Start.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

To get it to appear on the next form, you can update Form2's constructor.

```
private DateTime _dt
public Form2(DateTime dt)
{
    _dt = dt;
    this.Text = dt.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Then when you open that form, pass in the DateTime object from the calendar

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(dtObjectFromCalendar);
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Form2 can then display the month name as shown above.

As per comment, you can pass a string instead.

```
public Form2(string textToDisplay)
{

    this.Text = textToDisplay;
}
```

You can then call that form like this (assuming you keep the code in your question)

```
//this.Text because you set the value of this.Text in your question
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this.Text);
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I'm getting error: The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: At the top of your code, add this `using System.Globalization;` As a quick tip, if you get that error, VS can automatically try and add that `using` statement for you. Press `CTRL` + `.` after clicking on the class with the error (`CultureInfo` in this case) and an option box will pop up where you can add the correct `using` statement.

Comment: You need to pass that data into the Form2 constructor (you'll have to add that constructor yourself in your Form2 class). So open Form2.cs and you'll see `public Form2()`. This is the existing default ctor. You can add a new one (or replace this one if you want to enforce an object being added). The new one will look like the second code I added. Instead of a `DateTime` object, you could just change that to `string` and pass in the `this.Text` string. I'll update the code with the string option.

Comment: I got error: The name 'dtObjectFromCalendar' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @deepz - That was just an example. You need to replace that with the object from the calendar. I've updated the code to accept a string instead and should work with the existing code in your question.